# differentiate directly without function of function rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So the task is that I should calculate the antiderivative of $$(6x-2)^\frac{1}{3}.$$

The solution takes the approach of exchanging $6x-2$ with a $t$ and then writing $$t^\frac{1}{3}.$$

You add $1$ to the exponent and multiply with $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ (the multiplier of $x$ in the root):
$$\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot (6x-2)^\frac{4}{3}.$$

The correct solution is: (derivative of $v(u(x)$) times $6$ (derivative of $u(x)$).

$$\frac{1}{8}\cdot (6x-2)^\frac{4}{3}.$$

I tried to calculate by directly adding one to the exponent and then multiplying with $\frac{3}{4}$.

My solution would be: 
$$\frac{3}{4}\cdot (6x-2)^\frac{4}{3}.$$

Why is mine wrong, can someone explain this to me. I know that I'm doing something wrong because if I use $1$ for $x$ the solutions come out different.

Comment: Please read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've hopefully formatted the code correctly now

Comment: Because of the factor $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is $$\int x^n dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ or for example $$\int u^n du=\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ (these 2 are basicly the same, I just wanted to show you different notations).

But you used the rule in its wrong place because you have $\int u^n dx$ (different than the above forms).

Now this case have a different rule and that is $$\int u'u^n dx=\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

In your case $u=6x-2$ then $u'=6$, so you have to solve it this way,

$\int (6x-2)^\frac{1}{3} dx=\frac{6}{6}\int (6x-2)^\frac{1}{3} dx=\frac{1}{6}\int 6(6x-2)^\frac{1}{3} dx$

Now you have the above form $\int u'u^n dx$ so you can apply the rule and you'll get,

$\frac{1}{6}\int 6(6x-2)^\frac{1}{3} dx=\frac{1}{6}.\frac{3}{4}(6x-2)^\frac{4}{3}=\frac{1}{8}(6x-2)^\frac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply by $\frac{1}{6}$ for "cancelling the inner derivative". When you differentiate your solution, you obtain with the chain rule

$$\left ( \frac{3}{4} \cdot (6 x - 2)^{\frac{4}{3}} \right)' = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot (6 x - 2)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot 6 = 6 \cdot (6x - 2)^{\frac{1}{3}}  \neq (6x - 2)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Therefore, one has to divide through the inner derivative. In general, if $f$ is continuous, $a \neq 0$ and $F$ is an antiderivative for $f$, then one has

$$\int f(ax+b)\ \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{a} \cdot F(ax+ b) + c$$

with $c$ an integration constant. This is true since

$$\left ( \frac{1}{a} \cdot F(ax+ b) + c \right)' = \frac{1}{a} \cdot a \cdot f(ax+b) = f(ax+b).$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply by $\dfrac{1}{6}$ to get the correct answer, because if you differentiate $(6x-2)$ with respect to $x$, you get $6$. So, when you try to get the anti-derivative, you need to "undo" the multiplication by $6$, therefore you need to divide by $6$; i.e multiply by $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

My suggestion to you is to start with $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{8}(6x-2)^{\frac{4}{3}}$, and apply the chain rule STEP-BY-STEP to conclude that the derivative with respect to $x$ is
\begin{align}
\dfrac{df}{dx} &= \dots =  (6x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align}

Then, here comes the important part: work backwards step-by-step to try to convince yourself why multiplying by $\dfrac{1}{6}$ to your wrong answer gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that

$$\color{red}{\left((6x-2)^\alpha\right)'=\alpha(6x-2)^{\alpha-1}}$$ because of the $6$.

What is right is

$$\left((6x-2)^\alpha\right)'=6\alpha(6x-2)^{\alpha-1}$$ and you can translate this to the antiderivative.

---

Alternatively,

$$(6x-2)^{1/3}=6^{1/3}\left(x-\frac13\right)^{1/3}$$

and $$\int(6x-2)^{1/3}dx=6^{1/3}\frac34\left(x-\frac13\right)^{4/3}=\frac3{4\cdot6}\left(6x-2\right)^{4/3}$$